# Zoomable scatter chart

Tags: scatter-plot, qlikview

In Qlikview 11 I managed to set up (amongst others) a nice scatter chart without any major problems. Now I would like to be able to zoom into a region in that chart. Intuitively this could be accomplished by selecting a rectangular region with the mouse. Incidentally this works fine in "regular" line or bar charts. The new x and y axis regions correspond to the selected rectangle. However this does not happen with my scatter chart. I suspect this has something to do with the way dimensions are handled in scatter charts. For easier understanding I appended to screen-shots of the status quo - or how I don't want it to be.
[Full chart with selected region http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/4873/6ccc.png](http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/4873/6ccc.png)
[Chart displaying only the selected data http://imageshack.us/a/img138/9053/kck5.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img138/9053/kck5.png)

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, I would guess that the scatter plot has hard coded axis max and mins. Check the "Axes" tab under chart properties, and uncheck the scale boxes. That should allow the chart to zoom in.

Comment: Sorry, that's not it. The axis properties are all unset. Actually a dynamic axis has been chosen, which is the thing that seems to make scatter charts more complicated.

Comment: Have you tried actually adding a dynamic formula for the max and mins?  Formulas that depend on the max and mins of the possible measures?